# How to set up vim tags for JavaScript using vim-easytags

Tags: vimrc, plugin-you-complete-me, ctags

I use YouComplete plugin to do language completion but I can't seem to get tags to work for my own files/functions.

I use xolox/vim-misc and xolox/vim-easytags and installed Exhuberant ctags.

my .vimrc setup for easy tags as follows

```
"Amazing code completion
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

"tags
Plugin 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plugin 'xolox/vim-easytags'

" ----- xolox/vim-easytags settings -----
set tags=~/.vimtags
let g:easytags_events = ['BufReadPost', 'BufWritePost']
let g:easytags_async = 1
let g:easytags_dynamic_files = 2
let g:easytags_resolve_links = 1
let g:easytags_suppress_ctags_warning = 1
```

What do I have to do to make my custom functions show up in auto complete with YouComplete plugin